# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select  
  (
    (select Count(country_isoname) from games.country where country_olympic_code is null)
    /
    (select Count(*) from games.country)
  ) * 100 as 'Percentage'
from 
  games.country;
```

I am currently trying to get the percentage but getting an error, syntax looks correct i think? 
PLease help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
select (t1.specific_count/t2.all_count)*100 from 
(select count(country_isoname) as specific_count from country    
where country_olympic_code is null) t1, 
(select count(*) as all_count from country) t2;
```

Answer (score 4):

`'Percentage'` is a string literal. Object (column) names have be enclosed with double quotes.

So you need to use `"Percentage"` not `'Percentage'`